# Even after I install psycopg2 with pip, I still get No matching distribution found for psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I've been working on this over a week now, and the version problems just seem endless. I've downloaded a complex Django app, which has multiple install scripts. It is very complex.

I got an error that needed to be fixed by deleting Pipfile.lock, then I got some "missing module" errors and I manually did:

```
pip3 install importlib_metadata

pip3 install ConfigParser
```

but now I try:

```
pipenv lock
```

I get absolutely endless error messages, a small part of which looks like:

```
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/ec2-user/.local/share/virtualenvs/blueflow-c7ciKYpf/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pipenv-233zg4_c-build/psycopg2_a87c46885ac64bcd839843d942c021c6/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pipenv-233zg4_c-build/psycopg2_a87c46885ac64bcd839843d942c021c6/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' --no-user-cfg egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-t04x5e3y
     cwd: /tmp/pipenv-233zg4_c-build/psycopg2_a87c46885ac64bcd839843d942c021c6/
Complete output (6 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pipenv-233zg4_c-build/psycopg2_a87c46885ac64bcd839843d942c021c6/setup.py", line 225
    except Warning, w:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/ec2-user/.local/share/virtualenvs/blueflow-c7ciKYpf/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pipenv-233zg4_c-build/psycopg2_4e8ce76ba6cc49a19dc4f3ec22a582aa/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pipenv-233zg4_c-build/psycopg2_4e8ce76ba6cc49a19dc4f3ec22a582aa/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' --no-user-cfg egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-liszsbkl
     cwd: /tmp/pipenv-233zg4_c-build/psycopg2_4e8ce76ba6cc49a19dc4f3ec22a582aa/
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pipenv-233zg4_c-build/psycopg2_4e8ce76ba6cc49a19dc4f3ec22a582aa/setup.py", line 50, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
----------------------------------------
CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2 (from versions: 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.0.14, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.5, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4, 2.5.5, 2.6, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.3.1, 2.7.3.2, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.7.6, 2.7.6.1, 2.7.7, 2.8, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.8.5, 2.8.6, 2.9, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 743, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 711, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 693, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1385, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1106, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 884, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2
```

but the heart of it seems to be:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2
```

I'm trying to figure out how to install this, but I'm also curious if anyone has some meta level comment that might help resolve all of these errors.

I should add, I can do this:

```
pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

which succeeds, but then when I do this:

```
pipenv lock
```

I still get:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2
```

I also see this line:

"Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable"

If I knew where the normal `site-packages` was, I would make it writeable, but I have no idea.

If I try:

```
 pip3 install psycopg2
```

I get:

```
 Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

And also:

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/79/35c7596bab4456f3610c12ec542a94d51c6781ced587d1d85127210b879b/psycopg2-2.0.10.tar.gz#sha256=e40cc04b43849085725076ae134bfef9e3b087f6dd7c964aeeb930e2f0bc14ab (from https://pypi.org/simple/psycopg2/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2 (from versions: 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.0.14, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.5, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4, 2.5.5, 2.6, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.3.1, 2.7.3.2, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.7.6, 2.7.6.1, 2.7.7, 2.8, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.8.5, 2.8.6, 2.9, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2
```

I cannot afford to spend another week on this. I wonder if there is some way to break through and get everything working. Is there truly no way to get Python to do more of the work of figuring out what dependencies need to be installed?

Comment: Based on the first error message, it looks like you're trying to install a psycopg2 version that is for Python 2, but using pip for Python 3. Can you check what Python version your Django app is written in?

Comment: I think this app uses both Python2 and Python3. I don't have much experience with Python, but I thought this was common in the world of Python? Is there a way to get all this working? Most of the code works under Python 3.6, but there are some Python 2 libraries listed in the requirements.

Comment: Very few apps use both, it's most likely the case that your app is a Python 2 app where some parts coincidentally run under Python 3. You need to install and run everything for this app in Python 2 (which may need you to setup your PATH so that "python" points to "python2" when running the install scripts).